# In grid filter-field name will be changed into italic font

Tags: css, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I have kendo grid and tree-view with check-boxes.In my application grid is filtered based on the check-box selection.My requirement is when we check the check-box in tree-view,then filtering the grid,after filtering grid filtered columns headers will be change into "italic".my treeview code is

```
                 var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                  checkboxes: {
             checkChildren: true
              }, 

 dataSource: [{
     id: 1,
     text: "My Project",
     expanded: true,
     spriteCssClass: "rootfolder",
     items: [{
         id: 2,
         text: "OrderID",
         expanded: true,
         spriteCssClass: "folder",
         items: [{
             id: 3,
             text: "10248"
         }, {
             id: 4,
             text: "10249"
         }, {
             id: 5,
             text: "10250"
         }, {
             id: 6,
             text: "10251"
         }, {
             id: 7,
             text: "10252"
         }]
     }

     ]
 }]
      }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/79/

Answer (score 3):

I worked a lot and have found one solution for your code,

with one line of CSS :)

```
.k-filterable a.k-grid-filter.k-state-active ~ .k-link{font-style:italic;}
```

here is updated fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/81/

Enojy :)

Not sure of cross-browser compatibility, but works fine.